# Math Operations with Javascript in DIV created dinamically with classes

Tags: jquery, html, math, operation

After creating divs dynamically with class="sizetot"; i want to reset it's values when the sum of each div created is > to a certain number (storagemax) picked correctly from the database with php.
I have some problems, last divs created won't change their values.

```
    var storagemax1 = {!! json_encode(array_values($storagespers)) !!};;
       var sizetot = document.getElementsByClassName("sizetot");


       var value = Object.keys(sizetot).length;

       for (var k = 0; k < value; k++) {
           var storagevalue1 = sizetot[k].value;

           if (storagevalue1 - storagemax1 <= 0) {
               result = storagevalue1 + " GB  can be used.";
               document.getElementsByClassName("negativenumberchecker24")[k].innerHTML = result;
           }
           else {

               result = storagevalue1 + " GB can't be used. Insert a new value.";
               alert(result);
               sizetot[k].value='0';
           }

           var sum = 0;
           $('.sizetot').each(function () {
               sum += parseFloat(this.value);
           });
           if(sum>storagemax1){
               result = storagevalue1 + " GB can't be used. The maximum Storage of the LVM's avaibility has been reached. Insert a new value.";
               alert(result);

               for( let f = 0; f<10 ; f++ ) {
                   sizetot[f].value = '0';
               }


           } document.getElementsByClassName("negativenumberchecker24")[k].innerHTML = result;
       }
   }
```

The html code is:

```html
<input type='number' min="1" value="0" change="check_number24(this) name='sizetot[]' class='sizetot form-control'>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're missing a closing quote in the string. Assuming that's just a typo in the question, then there's not enough information here to be able to help you. Could you create a snippet with all relevant HTML and JS so we can see a working example of the problem.

Comment: Check console you must be getting syntax error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have edited my question. Check it out, thank you

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
    at check_number24 (instancesform:1266)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (instancesform:449)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing  `sizetot[f].value = '0';` to `this[f].value='0';`.
Thank you guys anyway!